# VirtualBox: guest network reconnects frequently

Tags: virtualbox, networkmanager

I have a KaLi 2.0 Linux (debian based) virtual machine. The network disconnects and re-connects frequently (in an experiment using ping this happened after 870, 960, 1480, 1567, and 1770 seconds).

I use VirtualBox is 5.0.10r104061 (64bit), the host runs Windows 7 SP1 64bit, the guest is Kali 2.0 (64 bit /w kernel 4.0.0-kali1-amd64). The connection is established by NetworkManager (version 0.9.10.0).

The relevant log excerpt is as follows:

```
Jan 13 12:39:17 xyzzy NetworkManager[576]: <info> (eth0): link disconnected (deferring action for 4 seconds)
Jan 13 12:39:21 xyzzy NetworkManager[576]: <info> (eth0): link disconnected (calling deferred action)
Jan 13 12:39:21 xyzzy NetworkManager[576]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [100 20 40]
[...]
Jan 13 12:39:21 xyzzy NetworkManager[576]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 13 12:39:21 xyzzy NetworkManager[576]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 13 12:39:21 xyzzy dbus[606]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jan 13 12:39:21 xyzzy dbus[606]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 13 12:39:21 xyzzy nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'down' for eth0
Jan 13 12:39:23 xyzzy NetworkManager[576]: <info> (eth0): link connected
Jan 13 12:39:23 xyzzy NetworkManager[576]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Jan 13 12:39:21 xyzzy NetworkManager[576]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed') [40]
```

So the carrier drops once in a while (or so NM thinks). This happens only for NAT; if I switch the NIC to bridge mode, this does not happen.

What is the reason for this, and how can that be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the symptom is still not clear. However, the issue can be "fixed" by removing the offending connection in NetworkManager and creating it from scratch.